# Error exporting Excel file in Laravel using Maatwebsite\Excel

Tags: excel, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I have an error exporting to an Excel file in Laravel. What am I doing wrong

> Message errror #message: "Method Illuminate\View\View::mergeCells does
> not exist."

```
namespace App\Exports;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromView;

class TimekeepingExport implements FromView
{
    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
     */
    public function view(): View
    {
        return view('backend.timekeeping.export-temp', [
            'items' => $this->data['items'],
            'detail' => $this->data['detail'],
            'getDays' => $this->data['getDays'],
            'getDates' => $this->data['getDates'],
            'total_day_request' => $this->data['total_day_request'],
        ])->mergeCells('A1:E1');
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... `mergeCells` would have to be called on a 'sheet'

Comment: i want use view to export .Can i use mergeCells ??

Comment: you can use a view to export but the `mergeCells` call has to be on a sheet not the view, you would have to figure out what method to override or define that would allow you access to the sheet object to call that on

Answer (score 0):

As the error message suggests, "mergeCells" is not a valid method on the Illuminate\View\View class, so you cannot add it to the end of the view return.

Comment: you can help me??